# Difficulties with Jupyter tab auto-complete

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm a relative newbie in python (i.e a few months) and have moved on to data science libraries and Jupyter notebook as per my needs. I'm however having problem with autocomplete coming from traditional IDEs and editors like Pycharm, VScode and IDLE and I am not sure if these issue are fundamental design decisions (flaws?) within Jupyter, or if I am misunderstanding or am having technical problems.

Firstly, when assigning a variable it is necessary to run the cell in order for Jupyter to suggest methods on below lines: this is not the case in pycharm for example which predicts the class of the variable.

Secondly, Jupyter is seemingly unable to detect the class of an object which has had methods or other actions performed (e.g filtering) on it, for example with data as a pandas dataframe:

```
data[data["columnA" == "A" ]].<TAB>
```

Will not generate suggestions, for example a `.sort_values()` method.
Is this to be expected with Jupyter?

Comment: Welcome. As to your first question, no, Jupyter can't introspect without the object being in memory. As to the second question, that particular line of code wouldn't run due to unmatched quotes and square brackets. Generally, if you get more than a layer deep with indexing on dataframes, don't expect tab auto-complete or introspection to work.

Comment: One way to overcome this is to assign new/temp variable, i.e. `tmp_df = data[data['columnA'] == 'A']`, in one cell, run it, and do `tmp_df.<TAB>` next cell. Since indexing only creates a slice, not copy, the overhead is minimal.

Comment: Thanks for the replies and suggestions. I've edited the incorrect code now (it was late) and will endeavour to post correct code in the future.